# What are the good techniques in debugging the Open AM in VM environment?

Tags: debugging, tomcat, virtual-machine, virtualbox, openam

I am new to OpenAM and trying to learn by setting up an authentication solution involving a SAML2 service provider, SAML2 IdP Server, SAML2 IdP proxy.

I have set this environment up on my Mac OS X having 3 VMs and using OpenAM, Virtual Box, Tomcat, and Vagrant to work with this.

I am familiar with few debugging and trouble shooting techniques like reading the log files and using the debugger of the IDE in a typical web application environment. I want to know what are the specific debugging and trouble shooting tools and techniques that I can use to trouble shoot various issues while working in this kind of environment. The difficult issues are the ones that occur within the VM, for example, a J2EE app deployed on the tomcat running inside the VM. Also, exception thrown by OpenAM.

Appreciate any specific tools and techniques.

Many thanks

Prabhu

Comment: As OpenAM and agents are open source you can always attach your favorite IDE debugger to the remote JVM and step through the code

Answer (score 0):

I would throw my vote on [cranking up OpenAM log levels](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Logging+Levels)

For debugging SAML communication, I have found [SAML Tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) to be a great tool.